# Make VIM normal-mode cursor sit between characters instead of on them

Tags: vim, cursor, normal-mode

I would really like it if the VIM cursor in normal mode could act like it does in insert mode: a line between two characters. So for example:
 - Typing vd would have no effect because nothing was selected
 - p and P would be the same
 - i and a would be the same

Has anything like this been done? I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: The idea that the cursor is always *on* a line and *on* a character position or column is inherent in Vim's design. If you were to try to change that, many of Vim's operations would behave differently or would not work at all. It's not a good idea. My advice would be that you learn and become accustomed to Vim's basic behavior and not try to make it behave like some other editor.

Comment: What you want is not Vim, I'm afraid.

Comment: "What you want is not Vim; I'm afraid" -- you're probably right about that. It's just I like having a "normal mode" where I can move around with l,j,k,h and yank/paste with single keypresses, and I don't know any other editor that does that.

Comment: there are Vim keybindings available for a few editors/IDE (Komodo, Eclipse, VisualStudio, TextMate…) but I think they mimic Vim's cursor behaviour quite literally; which is the way to go, IMO.

Comment: @romainl: can you explain why the `vim` way of handling cursors is better?  To really qualify as *better* it should be better for a beginner who has not learned to be accustomed to one approach or the other, so arguing from users habits is not valid.  Also, it should be better in a case where you were designing a new editor from scratch, so the fact that it would change `vim`'s behavior doesn't carry weight.  I can't see how it's better but I'm open to being shown how.

Comment: My suspicion is that it's more of a historical accident than a careful design decision, for instance: this is just the way Unix terminals worked, and so that model of cursor movement was never questioned but just adopted as-is and used in `vim`.  I suppose we'd have to ask Bill Joy for an authoritative answer...

Comment: Read my comment again but slowly: where do I say or imply that it's "better"? What I say is that an editor pretending to implement vi[m]-like bindings should follow vi[m]'s cursor behaviour as well. Whether you or new users like it or not is not important at all. But, since you are asking, I *think* that this behaviour is the most fitting with regard to Vim's general design. Block-wize selection, `x`, `s`, `r` or `%` would not exist if the cursor was between characters instead of `on` a character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just for fun, here's how you could achieve your desired behaviour for the examples you provided:

```
set selection=exclusive
set virtualedit+=onemore
" this is just a crude proof of concept with theoretically addressable weak points
nnoremap vd <Nop>
noremap p P
noremap a i
" make i<Esc> not move the cursor
inoremap <Esc> <Right><Esc>
```

But I hardly see the point. Care to explain why you want this? E.g. how is `vd` relevant and why not just use `i` and never `a`?

Comment: Heh, no `vd` isn't terribly relevant ;) but it would be nice if some vim "sentences" could be reordered like `dw` -> `vwd`, etc, which won't work because `vwd` grabs one char too many. Also trying to visually select the space between { and } when } is in the first column is tricky.

Comment: `dw` and `vwd` do the same for me within a line. On a line's last word they are different, which seems useful to me. There, you could replicate `dw`'s behaviour with `ved`. `cw` act different to what one might expect (it acts like `ce` instead of `dwi`), but a fix is offered in [:help cw](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#cw).

Comment: Regarding `{…}`, indeed even indentation is discarded with `vi{`. You could `va{` instead, but that also consumes the braces. The [`J` command](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#J) may be your (post)fix of choice here. It performs a line Join.  You could :map it into your preferred use[s] of `i{`/`a{`.

Comment: Really, `vwd` and `dw` do the same thing for you? I just tested it again to make sure I wasn't making stuff up and no, `dw` deletes a word and the following whitespace, whereas `vwd` also grabs the first char of the next word. Do you have some mapping that changes that behavior?

Comment: @Owen yup, definitely same thing. The behaviour you describe is odd and certainly not intended - have you checked your mappings? You can run a vim instance without any scripts with `vim -u NONE`

Comment: @accolade: Yes, it happens with `vim -u NONE`. It seems like it *should* too, shouldn't it? Since `w` takes you to the first char of the next word, and the visual block includes the char the cursor is sitting on.

Comment: @Owen yes, this is kind of embarrassing - I didn't test it with `vim -u NONE` myself. v_v The reason for my vim's behaviour is the option ['`selection`'](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27sel%27)=`exclusive`, which is default only under Windows (set by `mswin.vim`). I integrated this into my answer, too.

Comment: @accolade Oh! So it makes it like the cursor is between two chars! This is exactly what I wanted! (thank you!!)

Comment: @accolade I have a mapping much like your `inoremap <esc> <esc>l` but it is `inoramap <esc> l<esc> so it works everywhere.

Comment: @Owen Happy to hear that and thanks for the accept! :) I think you mean `ino <Esc> <Right><Esc>` and that's an excellent solution idea - I incorporated it into my answer!

Answer (score 4):

```
:set guicursor+=n:ver1
```

will make the cursor one pixel thin, so you can still visually distinguish Normal from Insert mode by it. If you want it to look exactly like Insert mode:

```
:se gcr+=n:ver25
```

`:help guicursor`([link](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'guicursor')) gives you this:

```
This option tells Vim what the cursor should look like in different
modes.
```

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Configuring_the_cursor has a great tutorial on the topic.

sidenote: the cursor in vim is *always* at a char, not 'in-between'. it just looks 'in-between' since it is a small vertical bar, bound to the left side of the char.

Answer (score 0):

For gnome version>3.15
Add this to your ~/.vimrc.

```
if has("autocmd")
  au VimEnter,InsertLeave * silent execute '!echo -ne "\e[2 q"' | redraw!
  au InsertEnter,InsertChange *
\ if v:insertmode == 'i' | 
\   silent execute '!echo -ne "\e[6 q"' | redraw! |
\ elseif v:insertmode == 'r' |
\   silent execute '!echo -ne "\e[4 q"' | redraw! |
\ endif
au VimLeave * silent execute '!echo -ne "\e[ q"' | redraw!
endif
```

You will get a block cursor in normal mode and a thin one in insert mode.